# Allow html in Bank Tranfer instructions

Tags: magento2

Magento removes all html for default Bank Tranfer payment method instructions.

How can I override that and allow html tags in instructions displayed in checkout page?

File used for displaying instructions is located here (probably)
`vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/banktransfer.html`

```
<p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your checkout page and write in html tags and save the file.your Data will not  remove.try it and good luck buddy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'edit your checkout page'. Which file do you mean? I think that checkout page has nothing to do with bank transfer payment. They are separate modules.

Answer (score 0):

Copy file banktransfer.html from

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/banktransfer.html

Paste banktransfer.html to

> app/design/frontend/{{Vendor}}/{{Themenane}}/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/

Change here : `<p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>` to `banktransfer.html` file

Remove pub/static/frontend/ and run command `php setup:static-content:deploy`